# DimDate Join to Another Table

Tags: sql

I have a DimDate table that I want to join to another table with dates where various visits took place. I have followed many threads on here, but I can't get the missing dates to appear in my result set.  Attached is a screenshot of my DimDate table and below is the script. I have two versions with the Dimdate table being the main table and the other version with it as a left join to the other table, and neither bring through the missing dates in my result set. Basically, I am trying to bring through all months and populate with a NULL if there are no entries in my other table.

```
  SELECT  
  month(d.date) as 'DimDateMonth'
   ,month(s.date) as 'ActivityMonth'
  ,year(d.date) as 'DimDateYear'
  ,[PCN]
  ,[Type of Visit]
  ,[Pharmacist]
  ,[Practice]
  ,count(distinct(cast(s.Date as date))) 'Number of visits'
  FROM [dbo].[DimDate] as d 
left join [dbo].[mytable] s on  month(d.date)  = month(s.date) and year(s.date)  =               year(d.date)

where s.Pharmacist = 'abc' and year(d.date) = '2020'

  group by 
   month(d.date)
    ,month(s.date)
  ,year(d.date) 
  ,[PCN]
  ,[Type of Visit]
  ,[Pharmacist]
  ,[Practice]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Filters on the *second* table in a `LEFT JOIN` need to be in the `ON` clause:

```
FROM [dbo].[DimDate] d LEFT JOIN
     [dbo].[mytable] s 
     ON month(d.date) = month(s.date) AND
        year(s.date)  = year(d.date) AND
        s.Pharmacist = 'abc' 
WHERE year(d.date) = '2020'
```

Putting the `s.Pharmacist = 'abc'` in the `WHERE` clause filters out `NULL` values -- which undoes the `LEFT JOIN`.

Note that conditions on the *first* table should still go in the `WHERE` clause so the rows really are filtered out.

I would also recommend writing the `WHERE` clause as:

```
WHERE d.date >= '2020-01-01' AND
      d.date < '2021-01-01'
```

This allows the query to use and index on `(date)` for filtering.

Comment: Wow! thank you so much. Very well explained and it worked. I really appreciate it.